# Как сделать не доходящий до конца border с прозрачностью?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть пример по которому нужно сделать галерею.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не могу сделать border как на примере.
Как сделать чтобы border у элемента был не на всю длину и размывался в конце?

Может кто то делал что то похожее.
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такой "костыльный" вариант:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

main {
  padding: 2rem;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0rem;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}

.grid-ul {
  height: 100%;
}

.grid:before,
.grid:after,
.grid-ul:before,
.grid-ul:after,
ul:before,
ul:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}

ul:before,
ul:after {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1px;
}

ul:before {
  top: 33.33%;
}

ul:after {
  top: 66.66%;
}

.grid-ul:before,
.grid-ul:after,
.grid:before,
.grid:after {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1px;
}

.grid:before {
  left: 25%;
}

.grid:after {
  left: 50%;
}

.grid-ul:before {
  left: 75%;
}

.grid-ul:after {
  left: 100%;
  content: none;
}

ul li {
  width: 25%;
  height: 33.33%;
  position: relative;
}

ul li span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  ul li {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 25%;
  }
  .grid-ul:before {
    top: 75%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 1px;
    width: auto;
  }
  .grid:before {
    left: 33.33%;
  }
  .grid:after {
    left: 66.66%;
  }
  ul:before {
    top: 25%;
  }
  ul:after {
    top: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  ul li {
    width: 50%;
    height: 20%;
  }
  .grid:after,
  .grid-ul:before {
    top: 60%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 1px;
    width: auto;
  }
  .grid:before {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .grid:after {
    top: 80%;
  }
  ul:before {
    top: 20%;
  }
  ul:after {
    top: 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-ul">
      <ul>
        <li><span>1</span></li>
        <li><span>2</span></li>
        <li><span>3</span></li>
        <li><span>4</span></li>
        <li><span>5</span></li>
        <li><span>6</span></li>
        <li><span>7</span></li>
        <li><span>8</span></li>
        <li><span>9</span></li>
        <li><span>10</span></li>
        <li><span>11</span></li>
        <li><span>12</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Кстати да, еще один вариант пробовала как у @stranger-in-the-q с градиентом, но приходится дублировать список :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

main {
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0rem;
  margin: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

ul:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 70%);
}

ul li {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  transform: translate(-2px,-2px);
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul li span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

ul+ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

ul+ul:after {
  content: none;
}

ul+ul li {
  border:none;
}

.grid {
  position: relative;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  ul li {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  ul li {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="grid">
    <ul>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
      <li>&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><span>1</span></li>
      <li><span>2</span></li>
      <li><span>3</span></li>
      <li><span>4</span></li>
      <li><span>5</span></li>
      <li><span>6</span></li>
      <li><span>7</span></li>
      <li><span>8</span></li>
      <li><span>9</span></li>
      <li><span>10</span></li>
      <li><span>11</span></li>
      <li><span>12</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Костыльным бы был, если бы градиент был на border'ах))

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

Вот такая попытка (`CSS`)

```css
.grid1, .grid2, .mask {
  position:absolute;
  width:220px;
  height:170px;
  top: 0;
}
.grid1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: solid gray;
  border-left: solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
.grid2 span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-top: solid;
  border-left: solid;
  text-align: center;
  border-color: transparent !important;
  line-height: 50px;
}
span:nth-child(5n+4) {
  border-right: solid gray;
}
span:nth-child(n+11) {
  border-bottom: solid gray;
}
.mask {
 background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, 
                             rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, 
                             rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 70%, 
                             rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div style="position:absolute">
  <div class="grid1">
    <span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><br>
    <span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><br>
    <span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="mask"></div>
  <div class="grid2">
    <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><br>
    <span>5</span><span>6</span><span>7</span><span>8</span><br>
    <span>9</span><span>10</span><span>11</span><span>12</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!